# Facebook release key hash for android not working

Tags: android, facebook, hash, apk, facebook-android-sdk

To generate my release key hash I do

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Where of course I use my actual release key alias and actual release key path. Then I went on Facebook and added it under `Key Hashes` in Settings. But My release build is not working with it. My debug build worked fine with the debug key. Any ideas what's wrong?

Under what circumstances might my app be able to post photos to Facebook in debug mode but not in release mode? I am using the simple call

```
Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), photo, new Request.Callback() {
  @Override
  public void onCompleted(Response response) {
    Log.i(TAG, response.toString());
  }
});
```

Again, when I was using the debug key and build, it worked fine. Could the problem be Proguard? I am using the following lines

```
-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
```

Comment: have you added your release key in your manifest file?

Comment: When you run this command is ask you password ?

Comment: Yes the command asks for password and I type the same password that I use for exporting the release apk from eclipse

Comment: No I have not added the release key in the manifest. I didn't know I was supposed to do that. How do I do that?

Comment: My internet went down for a while. Comcast seems to be challenging the net neutrality thing by reducing the quality of my service as a whole. So it took about an hour to get back.

Answer (score 2):

To make sure your keyhash is correct you can verify using below code

```
 // Add code to print out the key hash
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "yourpackagename", 
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

imports

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.content.pm.Signature;
```

Comment: My internet went down and is now getting back up. Thanks for the response, but PackageInfo seems to not exist and does Signature. What are your imports? Thanks.

Comment: @KatedralPillon Added Imports.

Comment: Thanks. The printed key hash looks neither like my debug key nor like my release key.  So which key would it be? I testing in debug mode, of course (as opposed to released apk)

Comment: @KatedralPillon you need to sign your apk first and then connect your phone via usb cable and run the signed apk on phone. Check your logcat for the keyhash. Your keyhash will be ending with a '='.

Comment: Thanks. +1. Your method accomplishes the same thing as `keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`. But I am still left where I started :). Why is my release build not about to post?